# Xalan Transformer factory not found in JBoss eap 6.1

Tags: jboss, xalan, jboss-eap-6

We have an ear application with a singleton ejb which sets up JAXP configuration. 
We set the TransformerFactory system property via code, with System.setProperty():

```
System.setProperty("javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory", "org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl");
```

The jboss-deployment-structure.xml file content is the following:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
    <ear-subdeployments-isolated>false</ear-subdeployments-isolated>
    <deployment>    
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.apache.xalan" slot="main" export="true"/>
            <module name="org.apache.xerces" slot="main" export="true" />               
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

we got the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactoryConfigurationError: Provider org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl not found
```

If I use the following line of code instead of setting the system property, it works.

```
TransformerFactory.newInstance("org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl", TransformerFactory.class.getClassLoader());
```

I would like to know why it doesn't work.
Do I misunderstand something about JBoss modules class loading?

Comment: Xalan is pretty old stuff.  I think it's all built into JDK now.

Comment: I Know Xalan is the default implementation, but that's not the point, I would like to know why there's an error with JBoss

Comment: @landal79 Did you ever solve this?

Comment: The problem is related to how the jboss as class loading works. In the end we solved without setting the system property and letting jboss to load Xalan.